# jquery x-editable numeric input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, x-editable

In x-editable library. How to have a numeric input? That does not allow any letter in the input box.

I have tried this code

```
<a class="items" data-name="itemqty" data-title="Enter Item Quantity" data-type="text" href="#" id="itemqty" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"></a>

<script>
    function isNumberKey(evt) {
      var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;
      if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
          return false;
      } else {
          return true;
      }      
    }
</script>
```

but it does not work. If I used a normal input text it works but in x-editable it does not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

The following solution works for me:

```
    $('.editable').editable({
        type: 'text', 
        validate: function(value) {
            if ($.isNumeric(value) == '') {
                return 'Only numbers are allowed';
            }
        }
    });
```

It's important to return an error string (e.g. 'Only numbers are allowed') because otherwise x-editable doesn't recognice that the validation has failed.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.jmlcolly,.jumlahitem,.beratsatuan').editable({
    type: 'text', 
    inputclass:'lebar',
    showbuttons:false, 
    title: 'Enter new value' ,
    validate: function(value) {
        if($.trim(value) == '') {
         alert('This field is required');
         return false;
        }
        if ($.isNumeric(value) == '') {
            alert('This Number is required');
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `data-step="any"` , Instead of `step="any"`

Ex :

```
<span id="cost" data-type="number" data-pk="1" data-title="cost" class="editable editable-click" data-step="any" onclick="callFunctionEditable('cost');">58.54545                                                        </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not as easy as it sounds. You need to allow other keys like <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>-</kbd>, etc.

I suggest to use a plugin that have been used and tested already, like [Numeric](http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/), or at least look at their implementation.